# Python Keyframe selection event?

Tags: python, scripting, graph-editor

It is possible to catch keyframe selection event(graphclick) in Graph editor? Or  verify what lies under mouse cursor?

i try to script simple selection behaviour like C4D: When cursor above keyframe - translate, when above empty pane - border selection

Thanks!

[image: Sample]